# Find critical points (minima) from gradient (2D vector)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, maxima-minima

I'm trying to find critical points (minima) for a gradient in 2D space. The following are partial derivative and its polynomial equation:
[image]

[image: partial derivative]

To find critical points I will need to set gradient to 0 and solve for 2 vectors span across $x_1$ and $x_2$. Could anyone provide steps in finding critical point for multi-variable equations? I'm trying to self-study and having this problem solved as a reference will be very helpful to my learning progress.

Thank you!

Comment: The main problem is the solution for a nonlinear equations system. In general this should be done using iterative numerical methods but in the present case, due to a special formula structure, the solution is quite simple. Think that adding the two equations you get  $8(x_1+x_2) = 0$ so $x_1 = - x_2$ and now the solution appears $-4x_1^3+8 x_1+1=0$ that can be solved by Cardano's formula.

Comment: The objective function is **polynomial**. Hence, so is the gradient. Thus, finding where the gradient vanishes boils down to solving a system of polynomial equations. In this case, it is easy. For harder systems, take a look at [Gröbner bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gröbner_basis).

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo My initial thought of the question was not about the concept , but more of how I’m able solve the problem in exam setting with limited time available. Is Cardano the only way to solve for minima vectors?

Comment: If you add the two cubic equations, you obtain $8 x_1 + 8 x_2 = 0$. Hence, $x_2 = -x_1$, or $x_1 = - x_2$. Substituting, you obtain a cubic equation in either $x_1$ or $x_2$. Some cubic equations can be solved by visual inspection, if the exam question is designed properly. I do not know what you mean by "Cardano".

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Cardano as in Cardano formula, which will be very time consuming in exam setting.

Comment: Well, you could use the Cardano formula in this case. I would ask the teacher, however.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I think by desperate measure I’ll just eye for estimations XD...

Comment: Have you tried solving the cubic equation symbolically? The solutions are (relatively) long. Such problems are for computers, not humans.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo right I’ll bring that up to the professor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the gradient of a multi variable equation equal to zero will give you the (local)minimum, (local)maximum or saddle points.

In your case, even though the gradient equation system is non-linear, we note that adding the two equations we get $$8x_1 + 8x_2 = 0 \Rightarrow x_1=-x_2.$$

Now we just substitute it in either the first or the second equation of the gradient system. Doing it for the first equation yields 
$$-4(x_2+x_2)^3+8x_2-1=0\Rightarrow-32x_2^3+8x_2-1=0$$ 
Solving it (using numerical methods, for example) and using the fact that $x_1 = -x_2$, we get the following points:
$$(-0.13480, 0.13480), \quad (-0.41878, 0.41878), \quad (0.55358, -0.55358).$$

This is the contour plot of $F(x)$
[image]

Analyzing this plot (or doing it numerically) we conclude that:

- $(-0.13480, 0.13480)$: saddle point;
- $(-0.41878, 0.41878)$: local minimum;
- $(0.55358, -0.55358)$: global minimum.